# How to fix I scan QR code for show ar model but my camera after model apperar is low frame rate

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I have some problems. Before I scan QR code my camera is high frame rate, but after my model appear  my camera is low frame rate (i use ar core, java for my app)
(video from my camera: https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Ab0OzOw9Wr-jVEq97q6F5dVJnBGqCBS/view?usp=sharing)

```
 public void setImage(final AugmentedImage image){
    this.image = image;
    if(!modelRenderableCompletableFuture.isDone())
    {
        CompletableFuture.allOf(modelRenderableCompletableFuture)
                .thenAccept((Void avoid) -> {
                    setImage(image);
                }).exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    return null;
        });
    }
    setAnchor(image.createAnchor(image.getCenterPose()));
     Node node = new Node();
     Pose pose = Pose.makeTranslation(0.0f,0.0f,0.25f);
     node.setParent(this);
     node.setLocalPosition(new Vector3(pose.tx(),pose.ty(),pose.tz()));
     node.setLocalRotation(new Quaternion(pose.qx(),pose.qy(),pose.qz(),pose.qw()));
     node.setRenderable(modelRenderableCompletableFuture.getNow(null));
 }
```

Comment: It's because of performance obviously. There is no switch to boost your Camera experience. How you are writing objects on Camera `Surface`?

Comment: when I try simple ar core of google (app for test ar of google) it not low frame rate.I following video for code (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1lu4PenfVWc&t=553s)

Comment: Show the code, how you are parsing QR code. Maybe you are parsing it `while-true`.

Comment: ok I wii post on my post